# NSUserNotification only display once if invoked in application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsnotificationcenter, corespotlight

I am developing a simple spotlight extension on macOs. My app will index some content into spotlight. When I type some keywords, spotlight will trigger app's [application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplicationdelegate/1428471-application?language=objc). And the application() will send a local notification. The code looks like this:

```
func application(_ application: NSApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: ([NSUserActivityRestoring]) -> Void) -> Bool {
    let notification = NSUserNotification()

    notification.title = "title"
    notification.subtitle = "subtitle"
    notification.soundName = NSUserNotificationDefaultSoundName

    NSUserNotificationCenter.default
        .deliver(notification)
}
```

And I use **macOs 10.14.3**.

If my app does not running, and I type the keyword in spotlight, the spotlight will start my app and run the `application()`. And I will see the notification correctly.

However, if I type keyword again(my app is running background), the spotlight still tigger the `application()` method but the notification does not appeared. Even worse, I could see the notification in the notification center.

Anyone can make help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To be displayed separately, each notification mush have a unique identifier.

```
notification.identifier = "different_kind"
```

From the documentation (emphasis mine):

> The identifier is unique to a notification. A notification delivered
>   with *the same identifier as an existing notification* replaces the
>   existing notification rather than causing the display of a new
>   notification.

There are also limitations on how quickly you can post new notifications, so be aware of that.

Finally, if your'e developing for Mojave, you should probably be looking into `UNUserNotificationCenter`, as `NSUserNotificationCenter` is deprecated.